# Why need cast generics when use 'extends'?

Tags: java

Why need cast to `List<T>` when using `T extends A`?

```
class A{}
public <T extends A> List<T> someMethod() {
    List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<T> result1 = list; // !! Does not compile, why?
    List<T> result2 = (List<T>) list; // ok, but why need cast?

    return  result2;
}
```

Comment: Because `list` can contain values that are not `T` but `A`..

Comment: When you write `T extends A`, you are saying `T` *is-a* `A`, but not `A` *is-a* `T`, because `A` can be a `T`, but not necessarily. Therefore, a list of objects of type `A` is not necessarily a list of object of type `T`.

Comment: "T extends A" means "subclasses of A and not A" or "subclasses of A and A"?

Comment: Imagine you have added an `A` to `List<A> list`, then all of a sudden you do `List<T> result1 = list; T object = result1.get(0)` and try to call a method on `T object` that your class `A` doesn't have and is only defined for a `T`.

Comment: Think of it like this. Apple is a Fruit but not all fruits are apples. You can but apple in a list of fruits. But you cannot but all fruits in a list of Apples, because Oranges are also a fruit.

Comment: But `T extends A`. Interface of T limitited by A. Not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the documentation about "Wildcards and Subtyping"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html): in your example `List<T>` is a subtype of `List<A>`. You cannot assign an instance to a variable of its subtype.

Imagine a simpler case: `Number` and `Integer`:

```
Number n = ...;
Integer i;
i = n;  // error
i = (Integer) n;
```

You can cast the compile error away, and that works fine as long as you know what is happening to your variables. If `n` was a `Double`, though, you would get a `ClassCastException`.

---

With collections like the ones in your example, the cast would always work, since the generic type information is not checked at runtime, i.e. it just casts from `List` to `List`.

But when you have generic types like `List`, there is another level of complexity: With the generic type, you give a kind of guarantee what that list contains (think of it like a promise to yourself, fellow developers using the code, and the compiler). By assigning a "wider" list, you can get into trouble when using it later.

```
class Apple extends Fruit
class Orange extends Fruit

List<Fruit> fruitBasket = Arrays.asList(new Orange(), new Apple());
List<Apple> applesOnly;
applesOnly = (List<Apple>) fruitBasket;

for (Apple apple : applesOnly) // ClassCastException because of the Orange in fruitBasket
```

In this example, you broke the promise that `applesOnly` contains only apples by assigning `fruitBasket`. That's why most IDEs would give you at least a warning when casting generics.